# Adding JDBC driver to AWS Glue for existing Spark code

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I am trying to run existing Spark (Scala) code on AWS Glue.

This code uses `spark.read.option("jdbc")` and I have been adding the JDBC driver to the Spark classpath with the `spark.driver.extraClassPath` option.

This works fine locally as well as on EMR, assuming I can copy the driver from S3 to the instances first with a bootstrap action.

But what's the equivalent on Glue?  If I add the driver to the "dependent JARs" option, it doesn't work and I get the "no suitable driver" error, presumably because the JAR must be visible to Spark's own classloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your job and at the end of the screen, you can see the libraries option.

And some options are needed, see the last part of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html).

---

[image]

Comment: I added my JAR to "dependent jars path" and that works for my other Scala classes but not for the JDBC driver.

Comment: it seems that yiu have to add some extra options.

Comment: OK, this may be a really dumb issue on my part - I think I had typos in the JDBC URL, jdbc:vendor:hostname instead of jdbc:vendor://hostname, and that showed up as a "no suitable driver" error.

Comment: Always, and Everyone. :)